# S Object and Standard Object

Tags: sobject

What is the difference between a S Object and Standard Object?

Comment: Possible dupe: [Can someone please explain what is meant by sObject?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/131733/2995)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone please explain what is meant by sObject?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/can-someone-please-explain-what-is-meant-by-sobject)

Answer (score 2):

Standard Objects *are* types of SObject, as are Custom Objects, Custom Settings, and many other types of metadata.

Comment: This is stated backwards. SObjects are type of Objects.

Comment: @sfdcfox `SObject` is just one type of `Object` in the context of `Apex`, but that is not what the OP is asking (according to my reading). They are asking to differentiate between *SObject* and *Standard Object*.

Answer (score 0):

An Object is any type of value that can be represented. They can be Integers, Strings, Booleans, custom classes, SObjects, and more. Sobjects are specific subtype that represents database records, including standard objects like Accounts and Cases, custom objects, custom settings, and custom metadata.